# Setting src of <img> in a Polymer Element

Tags: html, css, image, data-binding, polymer

Below is the code for my polymer element
I have tried normal dom binding with  and everything works fine

The src of the img however does not work.
I checked the html in chrome dev tools and it showed the src all wrong

The src here says /img/12.jpg which means the image is in the folder the html file is in
It however refers to the root of the folder instead

Expected src in dev tools: http://localhost:3000/elements/image-hover/img/12.jpg

Observed src: img/12.jpg

What can I do insted of harcoding it to the expected src?

```
<dom-module id="image-hover">
             <template>
                <img src="{{imgsrc}}"/>
             </template>
        </dom-module>
        <script>
          (function() {
            Polymer({
              is: 'image-hover',

              properties: {
                imgsrc: {
                    type: String,
                    value: 'img/12.jpg'
                }
              }
          });
          })();
       </script>
```

Edit: I have solved this issue by using the content tag provided by polymer.

```
<content id="image" select="img"></content>
```

The question still remains how can I figure out the source of the folder the element is in.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

```
<dom-module id="image-hover">
    <template>
        <img src="{{imgsrc}}"/>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'image-hover',

        properties: {
            imgsrc: {
                type: String,
                value: function () {
                    return location.host + "/img/12.jpg";
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The `value` is now a function that returns a `String` using the location object. More information can be found on that [here](http://The%20location%20object%20contains%20information%20about%20the%20current%20URL.). Put simply, it contains information about the current URL.

Comment: in my case, location.host returns localhost:3000 instead of localhost:3000/elements/image-hover

Comment: have you tried just doing `value: function () { return "/image/12.jpg"; }` ?

Comment: Doesn't work and I don't think it should...

The path is /elements/img/12.jpg

Even so, I don't want ahardcoded solution... more of a general one

Answer (score 4):

You can use [this.resolveUrl](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-resolveUrl) as follows:

```
          properties: {
            imgsrc: {
                type: String,
                value: function() {return this.resolveUrl('img/12.jpg')}
            }
          }
```